# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol in this case ? Cause?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am getting the following Linker Error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > __cdecl myjb::GetLocalAppPath(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &)" (?GetLocalAppPath@myjb@@YA?AV?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@ABV23@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall inmessage::init_service_thread(void)" (?init_service_thread@inmessage@@AAEXXZ)
```

I have the following method

```
void inmessage::init_service_thread()
{
   std::string appDataFName = (CT2CA) myjb::GetLocalAppPath("");
}
```

Now GetLocalAppPath is a function from an external lib. Any suggestion on what might be going wrong or the cause of the linker error ?

Comment: Are you linking to the import library for the external dll?

Comment: Yes I am linking to a lib file

Comment: You are importing the function with C++ name decoration. C++ name decoration is not standardized. Are you using the import library that was specifically compiled for use with your version of your compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason is the external dll doesn't implement GetLocalAppPath. And if the definition of GetLocalAppPath interface is not PURE virtual function, it would cause the same link error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a macro in a way that prevents the macro from being expanded. A macro is only ever expanded if it is followed by an opening `(`.

```
(CT2CA) myjb::GetLocalAppPath("");
```

This line of code prevents the macro from being expanded. This is a good thing, too, since it would pretty much just appear to work, by pure accident.

Use this instead:

```
CT2CA( myjb::GetLocalAppPath("").GetString() );
```

This is, of course, assuming that `GetLocalAppPath` is either a function in namespace `myjb` or a static function of class `myjb`. Either way, you are trying to import it with a `__cdecl` calling convention. Make sure this does match the exported calling convention.